# Using React with Electron such that Node.js native modules can still be used

Tags: node.js, reactjs, electron

I am trying to use `crypto.scrypt()` **from Node.js Crypto** in my React app, running inside Electron v11.2.1.

Currently, I am using `react-scripts start` to start the development server.

I then start the Electron app, which in *main.js* is configured like this:

```
mainWindow.loadURL('http://localhost:3000');
```

In my React app:

```
const nodeCrypto = require('crypto');
```

**The problem:** if I do `console.log(nodeCrypto)`, the object does not contain `scrypt` or `scryptSync`.

---

If, on the other hand, I make a new simple Electron project and **don't use React**, but instead configure it like this:

In *main.js*:

```
mainWindow.loadFile('index.html');
```

In *index.html*:

```
<script>
    require('./renderer.js');
</script>
```

And in *renderer.js*:

```
const nodeCrypto = require('crypto');

console.log(nodeCrypto);
```

I can see `scrypt` and `scryptSync` in the console log of `nodeCrypto`, as I would expect.

---

Now, my theory is this: because the React app is running "separately" on `http://localhost:3000`, it isn't using `crypto` from the [native Node.js module](https://nodejs.org/api/crypto.html#crypto_crypto_scrypt_password_salt_keylen_options_callback), but instead using it from somewhere else. I could be wrong.

My question is... how can I run the React app in the development server (so as to get live reloading during development) but still access Node.js native modules like `crypto` inside of Electron?

Comment: use this boilerplate https://github.com/electron-react-boilerplate/electron-react-boilerplate

Comment: example https://github.com/fxnoob/voice-typing-for-desktop